# Как блок внутри контейнера вытнуть в левую часть страницы

Tags: html, css

```css
.main-block{
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto ;
  background-color:red;
}

.some-block{
  height: 100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.need-block{
  height: 100px;
  background-color:green;
  width: 100vw  
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="some-block"></div>
  <div class="need-block"></div>
  <div class="some-block"></div>
</div>
```

Вот пример и мне нужно, чтоб зелёный блок был на всю страницу и начался с самой левой части страницы. Как это реализовать? Из контейнера я достать не могу и margin-left: сделать немогу(не знаю сколько, т.к. margin: o auto и не хочется отрицательных значений)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Растянуть дочерний элемент на всю высоту устройства](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542534/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто указать абсолютное позиционирование без указание top и всё ...

```css
.main-block {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.some-block {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.need-block {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="some-block"></div>
  <div class="need-block"></div>
  <div class="some-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, хорошее решение. Забыл про свойство left

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    const div = document.querySelector('.need-block');
    let margin = div.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    div.style.marginLeft = `-${margin}px`;
    div.style.width = `100vw`;
});
```

```css
.main-block{
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}

.some-block{
  height: 100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

.need-block{
  height: 100px;
  background-color:green;
  width: 100vw  
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="some-block"></div>
  <div class="need-block"></div>
  <div class="some-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @St1myL "нужно, чтоб зелёный блок был на всю страницу "

Comment: на всю. если ты имеешь ввиду при увеличении окна не изменяет свой размер, тот это событие не обработано. такая задача не стояла) а изначально блок на всю ширину страницы.

Comment: @St1myL ты не прав, в вопросе было написано на всю.

Comment: а вообще автору бы переделать разметку. довольно странная, мягко говоря...

Comment: @MadFox, когда говорил "На всю", под этими словами имел ввиду с начала левого края страницы))

Comment: @St1myL, внёс правки)